# AdvancedDataGrid editable property issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have an AdvancedDataGrid control with two columns UserName and eSigner. Which looks like:

[image: AdvanceDataGrid]

Code for this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="UserGroupGrid" left="10" bottom="40" right="10" editable="true" height="226">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                <mx:GroupingCollection id="gc" source="{UserGroupList}">
                    <mx:Grouping>
                        <mx:GroupingField name="UserGroupName"/>
                    </mx:Grouping>
                </mx:GroupingCollection>
            </mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn textAlign="left" headerText="UserName" dataField="UserName" editable="false"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="100" dataField="eSignor" headerText="eSigner" editable="true" textAlign="center" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="cbSelected" editorYOffset="30">
                     <mx:itemRenderer>
                         <mx:Component>
                             <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center">
                                <mx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        public var cbSelected:Boolean;
                                    ]]>
                                </mx:Script>
                                <mx:CheckBox id="SignorCk" width="10" selected="{data.eSignor}" enabled="true" click="cbSelected = SignorCk.selected;" visible="{data.eSignor == null ? false : true}"/>
                             </mx:HBox>
                         </mx:Component>
                     </mx:itemRenderer>
                 </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

As you can see in the code I want the column UserName to be non-editable and column eSigner to be editable. When I load up the page I am running into an issue where the grouping header Accounts Payable becomes editable. This happens when I click on Accounts Payable and then click somewhere off the browser and then click back on Accounts Payable again. It looks like this:

[image: AdvanceDataGrid1]

I have tried [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf651fa-7ff1.html) with less success. Since the column UserName has the editable set to false I wonder what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
itemEditBegin="preventEdit(event);"
```

The property above does the trick here. In the code posted, just add this property.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="UserGroupGrid" itemEditBegin="preventEdit(event);" left="10" bottom="40" right="10" editable="true" height="226">
```

In the script tag add the function:

```
private function preventEdit(event:AdvancedDataGridEvent):void
{
    if(event.itemRenderer.data.UserName == null) 
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Whenever we focus out and focus back in, on the grouping header, this would call the preventEdit function and that would cancel the events' default behavior of editing. I think this is just a workaround, hope they've fixed all this in Flex 4.

Source: [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#preventDefault())